# Addclass making img element not sticky in terms of position

Tags: jquery, css

I have this list of image as I'm making a gallery image. Whenever I click image there's active class being added via jquery but image position change also. How to make them sticky? See on sample  fiddle below if you click 
image, other images fall out to the next  time or it creates an empty space

http://jsfiddle.net/of6hLc0t/

```
$(".img").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

Comment: How do you mean _make them sticky_ ?

Comment: Each element wont move if element is being clicked they should stay on their position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* use [box-sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp). It will render the border inside the item instead. However, the image will shrink which will cause a sort of "blink".

Instead you can add a padding, which is removed when highlighted. You can also try *margin*, if you like it better.

```js
$(".img").click(function() {
    // Changed to toggle to better show the example.
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

```css
#imageconview {
  background-color: black;
  height: 430px;
  width: 350px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#imagecon img {
  /* Padding by default */
  padding: 5px;  
}

#imagecon img.highlight {
  border: 5px solid green;
    /* Remove padding when highlighted, since it's replaced by border. */
  padding: 0px;  
}

#imagecon img {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</div>



<div id="image_option">
 <div id="imagecon">

<div img="percon">
<img class="img" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/runescape2/images/d/df/Infernal_mage.png" alt="Smiley face" height="95" width="95">
</div>

<div img="percon">
<img class="img" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/runescape2/images/d/df/Infernal_mage.png" alt="Smiley face" height="95" width="95">
</div>

<div img="percon">
<img class="img" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/runescape2/images/d/df/Infernal_mage.png" alt="Smiley face" height="95" width="95">
</div>


<div img="percon">
<img class="img" src="C:\Users\edmtestuser\Desktop\Marlon Cristuta\images\photo_l_04.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="95" width="95">
</div>

<div img="percon">
<img class="img" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/runescape2/images/d/df/Infernal_mage.png" alt="Smiley face" height="95" width="95">
</div>

<div img="percon">
<img class="img" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/runescape2/images/d/df/Infernal_mage.png" alt="Smiley face" height="95" width="95">
</div>

<div img="percon">
<img class="img" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/runescape2/images/d/df/Infernal_mage.png" alt="Smiley face" height="95" width="95">

<img class="img" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/runescape2/images/d/df/Infernal_mage.png" alt="Smiley face" height="95" width="95">


 </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add box-sizing to your highlight class:

```
.highlight{
    border: 5px solid green;    
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/of6hLc0t/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
div > img{    border: 5px solid #f3f5f6; }
```

Use toggleClass() instead of addClass()

Comment: How does this help with the class change and the position of the image?

Comment: add this $(".img").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});

Answer (score 0):

[Updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/of6hLc0t/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/of6hLc0t/2/)

```
#imagecon img.img.highlight{
border: 5px solid green;                   
}


#imagecon img {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin-left: 3px;
margin-top: 2px;
border:5px solid white;//Add this

}
```